# Stuck using Wordpress Menu (maybe custom CSS Walker is needed)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, nav

I have been playing around for a while now with the Wordpress 3.6 menus. I have attached two screen shots of what I have so far.

This is what I want the menu to look like but currently it isn't a menu but the default display of pages with their nested child pages.

[image: Desired outcome]

You can see what it should look like in more detail in the image below.

[image: Pages with nested children]

I would like to change the current 'menu' system (pages, page-links-to etc) and make it a standard menu using wordpress' built in menu maker. However, when I do so, it breaks the CSS. I believe I need to create a custom walker to iterate through the menu items and generate HTML with the same structure as the original nested pages.

Currently, it looks like this.

[image: Wordpress Menu mess]

If anyone could offer any help and support regarding replicating the 'original' pages menu for this custom navigation menu it would be appreciated.

The URL is http://michaelnorris.co.uk/

Comment: Did you check what's the difference in the markup? Can you set your website to *break* so I can see myself?

Comment: Done. It is now using the Wordpress menu system rather than the default pages etc.

Comment: It looks like you put them all on the same hierarchical level, you have to drag the children slightly to the right of the parent element to make them work as children. Did you do that?

Comment: Thank you so much, it's sorted. Such an obvious error. I don't want to say how many hours that has cost me!

Comment: I will answer the question so you can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you put them all on the same hierarchical level, you have to drag the children slightly to the right of the parent element to make them work as children.

Answer (score 1):

If it works on the default menu, but not on custom menus then the walker is probably not the issue(but it could be.)

Let's start at the beginning.  Did you arrange the items in your custom menu into the hierarchical structure you want to achieve?

Comment: The pages (as they are now) are arranged in order and their children the same. I used the default layout for the menu (copies the pages etc) so that should be the same. Apparently the HTML markup is different from the menu, or at least it appears to be... Any suggestions?

Comment: It's been a while on this, but if you haven't solved it I'll take another stab.

When you create a new custom menu, there is no default layout, when you select an item(s) to be put into the menu and click add, they are all added at a depth of 0.

If you want an item to be at depth 1 or higher, you have to click and drag each and every one into the hierarchical position you want it to appear in.This is what creates the proper markup to appear as a dropdown.  This is because dropdown css targets elements with a depth of 1 or higher.

Comment: Tom, @Sunyatasattva already provided the correct answer on Sep 20. Thank you though.

Comment: Doh! I didn't see that. Glad you got it figured out.